# strange behaviour of regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have this str list

```
l=['Cu_3', 'P_2', 'O_8']
```

and this two regexp

```
import re
sub = re.compile('_([0-9])')    
sub2 = re.compile('._([0-9])')
```

sub doesn't match any elemetn of the list, while sub2 matches the last two but not the first one..
I am probably missing something but I expected to capture the numbers after the underscore with both of them. What's the problem here?

Comment: You didn't show the code where you did the matching.  Best guess: you used `re.match` instead of `re.search`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `match()` method instead of the `search()` method, so your regexs are anchored at the start of the string.

Comment: You're damn right, i didn't know that about re.match(), thx a LOT!

Comment: If he were using `match` then `Cu_3` should not match because `._([0-9])` is just one of any character at the start of the line. Good detective work tho!. +1